# AIR 3 on Galaxy tab fullscreen (impossible ?)

Tags: air, adobe, galaxy-tab

How does one set AIR3 application to fullscreen mode on Galaxy Tab ?

I have tested with button that triggers FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE as well FULL_SCREEN but these dont have any effect on the tab. I still see to bar down below with home button and clock'n'stuff....